# How to get return type string of a method using Scala reflection?

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

consider the following code:

```
object Foo{def foo(a:Int):List[(String, Int)] = ???}

class Bar{def bar(a:Int, b:Any):Option[(String, Long)] = ???}
```

Given either the object or class, I need to first find the method names (does not seem to be that difficult).

After that, for each method, I want to find a string description of the **Scala** return types (not the Java ones) . So for instance, for `Foo.foo`, I would need the String `List[(String, Int)]` and for `Bar.bar`, I would need the String `Option[(String, Long)]`.

I saw [this](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html) and [this](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html) tutorial but could not figure it out.

EDIT: Here is what I tried based on the comments:

```
class RetTypeFinder(obj:AnyRef) {
  import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
  val m = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
  val im = m.reflect(obj)
  def getRetType(methodName:String) = {
    ru.typeOf[obj.type].declaration(ru.TermName(methodName)).asMethod.returnType
  }
}
object A { def foo(a:Int):String = ??? } // define dummy object
class B { def bar(a:Int):String = ??? } // define dummy class
val a = new RetTypeFinder(A) 
a.getRetType("foo")  // exception here
val b = new RetTypeFinder(new B) 
b.getRetType("bar")  // exception here
```

The error I get is:

```
scala.ScalaReflectionException: <none> is not a method
at scala.reflect.api.Symbols$SymbolApi$class.asMethod(Symbols.scala:228)
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$SymbolContextApiImpl.asMethod(Symbols.scala:84)
at cs.reflect.Test.getRetCls(Test.scala:11)
...
```

However, this works (tried in REPL):

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
val m = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)

object A { def foo(a:Int):String = ??? } // define dummy object

val im = m.reflect(A)
ru.typeOf[A.type].declaration(ru.TermName("foo")).asMethod.returnType

class B { def bar(a:Int):String = ??? } // define dummy class

val im = m.reflect(new B)
ru.typeOf[B].declaration(ru.TermName("bar")).asMethod.returnType
```

I need to use it in the first way, where I don't know in advance what objects/classes will be passed. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For classes: typeOf(Bar).member(newTermName("foo")).asMethod.returnType

Comment: The same works for the object as well: `typeOf[Foo.type].member(TermName("foo")).asMethod.returnType`

Comment: @Kolmar please see my edit for more details where I am stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have a `universe.Type` you can use the way from the comments to get the return type of one of its methods:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}

def getRetTypeOfMethod(tpe: ru.Type)(methodName: String) =
  tpe.member(ru.TermName(methodName)).asMethod.returnType
```

To get a `universe.Type` the easiest way is to capture in an implicit `TypeTag`:

```
class RetTypeFinder[T <: AnyRef](obj: T)(implicit tag: ru.TypeTag[T]) {
  def getRetType(methodName: String) = {
    val tpe = tag.tpe
    getRetTypeOfMethod(tpe)(methodName)
  }
}
```

But if you don't have a `TypeTag`, but just an object of type `AnyRef`, you can go through a `mirror` to reflect it. The resulting `Type` will have some information lost due to Java's type erasure, but it would still be enough to get the return type of a method by name, because that's supported by JVM reflection:

```
class RetTypeFinder2(obj: AnyRef) {
  def getRetType(methodName: String) = {
    val mirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
    val tpe = mirror.reflect(obj).symbol.info
    getRetTypeOfMethod(tpe)(methodName)
  }
}
```

Both methods work fine for your problem:

```
scala> new RetTypeFinder(A).getRetType("foo")
res0: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = String

scala> new RetTypeFinder2(A).getRetType("foo")
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = String

scala> new RetTypeFinder(new B).getRetType("bar")
res2: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = String

scala> new RetTypeFinder2(new B).getRetType("bar")
res3: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = String
```

Comment: I had to use `RetTypeFinder2` as the other didn't work (same error). I guess because the object/classes are defined in an different project.